# Error C2864 with static constexpr array in VS2013 (CTP_Nov2013)

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, visual-studio-2013, constexpr

Following is the code in the header:

```
struct FormContainer{
    enum Forms{ Stuff, FormCount};
    enum MoreForms{ MoreStuff = FormCount, MoreFormCount};
    static std::array<UInt32, MoreFormCount> Forms;

    static constexpr UInt32 FormArrayCount = 2;
    static constexpr char* FormArrayNames[FormArrayCount] { "AnArray", "2ndArray" };
    static constexpr UInt32 FormArrayEndingIndex[FormArrayCount] { FormCount, MoreFormCount };
};
```

Why does it give me the following error:

> error C2864: 'Common::FormContainer::FormArrayEndingIndex' : a static data member with an in-class initializer must have non- volatile const integral type

for the last two lines (the array initialisation)?

Comment: The ctp has incomplete constexpr support and that's probably the reason. You should fill a bug report on Microsoft Connect.

Comment: Found it...http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/12/02/c-11-14-core-language-features-in-vs-2013-and-the-nov-2013-ctp.aspx
"The CTP supports C++11 constexpr, except for member functions. (Another limitation is that arrays aren't supported.) Also, it doesn't support C++14's extended constexpr rules."